# for文を用いてlambda関数を辞書に格納する方法

Tags: python, lambda

定義を少しずつ変えた複数の関数を辞書形式で保持したいため、
以下の様なpythonのコードを考えました。

```
funcs = {}
for i in range(5):
    new_key = 'f'+str(i+1)
    funcs[new_key] = lambda x: x**i  #0次関数から4次関数を格納
```

しかしそれぞれの関数に引数を与えると、全て同じ値が返ってきます(最後に格納した関数の値)

```
for f in funcs.values():
    print(f(5))
```

実行結果：

```
625
625
625
625
625
```

これを(1, 5, 25, 125, 625)を返すようにしたいのですが、
どのようにすればよいかご教授いただけないでしょうか。

ちなみに、for文を使わずに一つ一つ手で格納すると正しく値が返ってきました。
また上コードにより格納された各関数のidは別々となっていました。

```
for f in funcs.values():
    print(id(f))
```

実行結果：

```
4503380040
4503310120
4503309984
4503309848
4503309168
```

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 6):

```
funcs[new_key] = lambda x: x**i  #0次関数から4次関数を格納
```

この行で、ラムダ関数が見ているiは、中身の値ではなく変数のiそのものです。for文の中では同じiが使いまわされるので、iが変更されれば、ラムダ関数が後でiを参照するときには、当然最新の値をとってくることになります。

解決方法の一例を挙げると

```
funcs[new_key] = (lambda j: lambda x: x**j)(i)
```

これはラムダ関数の引数の有効範囲は、そのラムダ関数の中だけであることを利用しています。`lambda j: lambda x: x**j`はラムダ関数を返すラムダ関数ですが、jの有効範囲は、この行だけなので、この行に来るたびに新しいjが作られ、使いまわされることはありません。`(lambda j: lambda x: x**j)(i)`で、iの値を実引数としてjにコピーすることで、funcsのラムダ関数が一つ一つが独自の値を持つことになります。

Comment: 分かりやすく解説して頂きありがとうございます！
おかげさまで解決できました。

Answer (score 0):

本家StackOverflow質問 [Python lambda's binding to local values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/) で紹介されてる別回答です。

ラムダ式のデフォルト引数を用いると、一部の値（ここでは`i`）をラムダ式による関数オブジェクト構築時点の値に束縛できます。

```
funcs[new_key] = lambda x, i=i: x**i
```